# Clone a module and make changes to the copy

Tags: python, inheritance, module, copy, python-3.x

Is it possible to copy a module, and then make changes to the copy? To phrase another way, can I *inherit* from a module, and then override or modify parts of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> To phrase another way, can I inherit from a module, and then override or modify parts of it?

Yes.

```
import module
```

You can use stuff from `module` or override stuff in your script.

You can also do this to create a "derived" module.

Call this "module_2".

```
from module import *
```

Which imports everything.  You can then use stuff from `module` or override stuff in this new module, "module_2".

Other scripts can then do

```
import module_2
```

And get all the stuff from module modified by the overrides in module_2.

Comment: I'm not sure that this affects the globals the imported classes use. If I import class `A` from module `moda`, `A` will still access global variables from `moda`.

Comment: @Matt Joiner: There's a trick to "module extension"  Don't reference the parent module.  In this example, you'd **only** import from the extension module, using the extension module name.  `module_2.A`.  If you use the base module name, you break it.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood, it doesn't seem to work the way you make it sound: All the classes imported from `moda`, still search `moda` for their globals. Even when subclassed and imported using the `from` syntax, the methods defined in `moda` still resolve global symbols there.

Comment: @Matt Joiner: `from module import *` imports everything.  Module name qualifications are not required.  Perhaps you should open a new question with your exact code and exact problem.  Or.  You could post your current code to *this* question.  It's much, much easier to work with actual code and actual error messages.

Comment: After raging a bit, I realised you are right. Here's (hopefully) the real question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7495886/use-a-class-in-the-context-of-a-different-module

Comment: I would not call this, or compare this with class inheritance. If module has 2 functions f1 and f2, and f1 calls f2, even if I `import *` them to my newmodule, newmodule.f1 still calls (old) module.f2 -- cross references are *not* updated. Wheres in class inheritance `self` provides the glue to make this happen.

Comment: @JürgenStrobel: Correct.  I tried to avoid making that comparison.  I provided a solution that's sort of like inheritance in one aspect of "extending" another module.

Answer (score 0):

The namespace of a Python module is writable. Consider:

```
# contrived.py
CONST = 100
def foo():
    return CONST
```

You can modify the value of `CONST` after it's been imported:

```
import contrived
contrived.CONST = 200
contrived.foo() # 200
```

However, only a single instance of a module can be imported so there is not anyway to create a clone and continue to use the original module. If you don't need access to the original module, then it's fairly straight-forward to create a wrapper module and override whatever you want to change.

One thing to look out for is that code like this will not work as you expect:

```
# clone.py
from contrived import *
CONST = 200
```

This will actually assign `CONST` in `clone`'s namespace, functions imported from `contrived` will continue to reference the `CONST` in `contrive`'s namespace:

```
import clone
clone.foo() # 100
```

In this case you could do something like this:

```
# clone.py
import contrived
contrived.CONST = 200
from contrived import *
```