# Modifying module globals using externally defined function

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

I have a very simple decorator function I use to expose functions defined in a module via the module’s `__all__` property. Because I use it for multiple modules within a package, I have it defined in the package’s `__init__.py`.

Because I cannot use `__all__` from within the definition, as it would refer to the `__all__` of the `__init__.py` module (or rather the package), I am currently doing it like this:

```
def expose ( fn ):
    fn.__globals__['__all__'].append( fn.__name__ )
```

This seems to work totally fine. However I’m not sure if using the `__global__` property is the ideal way to do it, especially as that property seems to be undocumented (at least I couldn’t find anything about it in the documentation).

Is using `__globals__` fine for that, or is there maybe an easier and more robust way to make this work?

#### edit:

For clarification, I don’t necessarily need to access the `__all__` property of the module. I can easily use a different name and end up with the same question. I’m just using `__all__` because its purpose of holding all exposed objects in a module matches my intention. But at the same time I could also name it `exposedFunctions` or whatever. So the question is more about how to access the global properties of the module.

Comment: Why do this? Then the list isn't all in one place in the source, which is one of the nice things about `__all__`.

Comment: Because the modules are used for multiple (i.e. a lot) small functions that should be exposed through `__all__`, and maintaining a huge list of function names is not so simple if you want to allow to easily add and remove functions from the module. Nevertheless, the question is not necessarily about modifying `__all__` but rather accessing any module-global from inside an externally definied function. – I could easily expose the functions via a property `foo` and leave the `__all__` the way it is, if that would make you happy ;) (i.e. I don’t use the import-mechanism behind that property)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might like Thomas Rachel's `AllList` decorator:

```
class AllList(list):
    """list which can be called in order to be used as a __all__-adding decorator"""
    def __call__(self, obj):
        """for decorators"""
        self.append(obj.__name__)
        return obj
```

Import it from whereever, and at the top of your module have

```
__all__ = whereever.AllList()
```

then in your module it looks like

```
@__all__
def some_func():
...

@__all__
def another_func():
...
```

and no need to worry about globals.

**Update**

If you really want to worry about globals, take a look at [Use a class in the context of a different module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7495886/use-a-class-in-the-context-of-a-different-module/7681482#7681482) -- it is not pretty, however.

Comment: That’s a pretty neat solution! I’ll definitely keep this in mind, thanks!